# Create a macro for mapping

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA and have a question about creating a macro to do mapping. For example if I have the following list in column A:

```
Apple
Volvo
Hyundai
Orange
Grape
Christmas
Thanksgiving
```

Now, I want to convert the items in column A based on the following mapping,

```
Apple, Orange, Grape --> Fruit
Volvo, Hyundai --> Car
Christmas, Thanksgiving --> Holiday
```

This is just a simple example, and I am hoping that I can get some help on the start so that I can expand on the macro.

Thank you!

Comment: so you already have a reference list where the mapping is based? also, you want to output it in one cell? Like what you show above?

Comment: Create a mapping table with two columns - `Name` and `Type`. Enter all your mappings in that table.  Then use `VLOOKUP()` to translate `name` to `type`

Answer (score 0):

A case statement would work well to evaluate the item.

```
Dim TheItem as string 
'~~~TheItem = ColumnA
Dim TheType as string = ""
Select Case TheItem.ToUpper

  case "APPLE", "ORANGE", "GRAPE" 
    TheType = "Fruit"

  case "VOLVO", "HYUNDAI"
    TheType = "Car"  

  case "CHRISTMAS", "THANKSGIVING" 
    TheType = "Holiday"

End Select
'~~~ColumnB = TheType
```

Note that the lines with '~~~ will need some work to read/write your columns.

It could get REALLY big...  If so, you may want to use a database instead.

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer. I have a question, why do we need both
Dim TheItem as string
and
Dim TheType as string = ""
?????

Also, i know how to target a single cell, how would I replace '~~~ so that it targets a whole column??

Comment: the line Dim TheType as string = "" is just to initialize the string.